# Sticky Bar Glitch in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

So I have a sticky bar and when it becomes fixed it has a little animation with before and after elements.

This works fine on Chrome but its slightly glitchy on firefox.

The site is live the link is:
http://pixelfriendlytech.co.za/

Simple demo is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/zr8gc1f7/4/

Here is the css:

```
#pf-bar{padding: 0px;
z-index: 1000;
top:0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
position: relative;
max-width: 2560px;}

#pf-bar:before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: calc(50% + 570px);
bottom: 0;
width: 0px;
height: 60px;
background-color: #fff;
border-bottom: 3px solid #2484C6;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
z-index: -1;}

#pf-bar:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;''
top: 0;
left: calc(50% + 570px);
bottom: 0;
width: 0px;
height: 60px;
background-color: #fff;
border-bottom: 3px solid #F72244;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
z-index: -1;}


.sticky #pf-bar:before {
width: calc(50% - 570px);}

.sticky #pf-bar:after {
width: calc(50% - 570px);}

.sticky #pf-bar{
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s;
transition-delay: 0.5s;'}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Always be specific and make your best effort before asking, and don't treat SO "Glitch searching" I didn't find your glitch in Firefox. And remember that Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please read about [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn how to write effective questions. I recommend you to put the HTML code for the bar also.

Comment: I can reproduce this "glitch" problem in Firefox 53 on Mac 10.12 -- a very quick "flashing" at the beginning of animation. Can you provide a minified code snippet, with HTML+CSS+JS (if there is JS)?

Comment: Hi i am not sure what a minify code snippet is but i create a demo on jsfiddle. It is not responsive so your preview window has to be quite big. https://jsfiddle.net/zr8gc1f7/4/